# Resetting textarea problem, "Cannot create property on string"

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea

So, I'm making a basic note taking app, and I have a text area and a submit button for the user to enter a note. I'm having trouble resetting the text area to be blank though after the button is hit. I tried finding a solution online but all I'm finding are solutions using jquery when I'm only using vanilla javascript on my front end.

Here's the html:

```
<textarea class="noteInput" rows="10" cols="46" placeholder="Click to start typing your note" maxlength="314"></textarea>
    <button class="submitNoteButton">Add Note</button>
```

And here's the javascript so far, the only problematic piece is the noteInput.value = "" at the end:

```
submitNoteButton.addEventListener('click', function submitNote() {
  let noteInput = document.querySelector('.noteInput').value; //Get input from the textArea
  noteList.push(noteInput); //Add the note to the array of notes to be displayed
  console.log(noteList);
  modalbg.style.display = 'none'; //Close the note after the submit button is 
pressed

  //If the user isn't logged in, no need to pull from the database
  if (!loggedIn)
  {
    let notes = document.querySelector('.notes'); //Notes div in the html
    if (notes.length != 0) //If there are already notes, clear them before doing the for loop
    {
      notes.innerHTML = '';
    }
    //For each note in the noteList, display it in the html
    for (let i = 0; i < noteList.length; i++)
    {
      let note = document.createElement('note'); //Create an element for each note
      note.innerHTML = noteList[i]; //Make the text of each note
      note.className = 'note';
      notes.appendChild(note); //Append each note to the notes div
    }
    noteInput.value = "";

  }

})
```

Everything's working how I need it to except this one little thing. It tells me "Cannot create a property on string" and then whatever string was last entered. Not sure why noteInput.value is being treated as a string and not a text area like I defined it to be. Any help?

Comment: Can you show where you defined noteInput in your js code?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had that in there, I updated the javascript block with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define noteInput to be the value of the textarea and not the textarea element itself. This should fix it

```
let noteInput = document.querySelector('.noteInput');
noteList.push(noteInput.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `noteInput.value = ""`
to
`noteInput = ""`